# How can I start class in a separate thread?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I would like to know. How can I start class in a separate thread? I want to handle external events in a separate thread. How I can do this. I tried to use infinite loop, but it did not help.

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {

                }
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
```

When I call  Show() method in the console printed id of main stream.

Comment: Start a class, as in create an instance?

Comment: Yes, for example. I'd like to do something like this. Task.Run (() => new Class1()); And that class existed during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: then use `Task.Run (() => new Class1().Run()); ` and call `Show` in your Run method.

Comment: To have an instance that exists the whole lifespan of your app you should just have it as static initialized field or declare it at the beginning of Main. Tasks are used for async programming and not as some use-it-everywhere-tool. If you want to execute some job continuously during the app's lifetime you should use some background thread, because TPL is designed to support the run-the-task-get-the-result model, not the run-the-service-use-it model

Comment: @Eugene i think you went a little overboard. He simply wants to know how to run the infinite loop on a different thread. `Task` isn't only for `async` or run the task and get the result, its an abstraction over the threadpool and thread creation

Comment: I meant that the Task is supposed to end somewhen, that it is just a piece of work to be done and reported(continued with another job), while the desired behaviour is service-like data processing. Well, you obviously can use it, but in **my opinion** it is just not the most direct example of Tasks' application.

Comment: @SergeiLukyanov Tasks aren't threads. They represent a single function call, not a never-ending thread. It makes sense to run whatever is *inside* the loop as a Task, not the loop itself. What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create the `Task` explicitly inside `Run`. Just create the `while(true)` loop inside `Run` and invoke it via `Task.Run`

```
public class Class1
{
    public void Run()
    {
       while (true)
       {
            // Do stuff in loop
       }
    }
}
```

Then call it:

`Task.Run(() => new Class1().Run(), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);`

Comment: That's a *very* bad idea because it wastes a ThreadPool thread. A Task (or a threadpool thread for that matter) should do one thing and finish, not block indefinitely. It's whatever is inside the loop that should run as a separate thread, not the loop itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That is not true. The [TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) flag will force the allocation a new dedicated thread for this task and not use one of the `ThreadPools`. He wants to create a sort of `MessageLoop` on a dedicated thread. I don't see anything wrong with that.